# Composing Tasks by passing nested Tasks as function arguments

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, asynchronous, async-await

For example, there is a function that produces value (maybe queries it from service):

```
async function GetValue() as Task(of double)
    await Task.Delay(1000)
    return 16
end function
```

and I want to write function that calculates something from the value (maybe calculates square root of the value).

One way to write this function is

```
async function Calculate(D as double) as Task(of double)

    await Task.Delay(1000)

    return Math.Sqrt(D)
end function
```

it will be used like

```
dim D = await GetValue
dim R = await Calculate(D)
```

Another way to write this function is

```
async function Calculate(T as Task(of double)) as Task(of double)

    await Task.Delay(1000)

    dim D = await T

    return Math.Sqrt(D)
end function
```

it will be used like

```
dim R = await Calculate(GetValue)
```

The second variant composes two tasks into one task to produce the final value.

1. Is it considered normal practice to pass Task (Promise / Future) as function argument to build task compositions?
2. Are there any arguments / situations against the second variant?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with any approach. However, the first option allows to handle synchronous operations without going into synch over async. In your particular example, `Calculate` real work has noting to do with asynchronous operations. Maybe you have a better use case.